# React JS: Component Not Exported

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

**I have below folder structure of my project :-**

[image]

**Within GlobalStore.js , I have code ->**

```
import React from 'react'

const GlobalContext=React.createContext();
const GlobalProvider=GlobalContext.Provider;
const GlobalConsumer=GlobalContext.Consumer;


export default {GlobalProvider,GlobalConsumer}
```

**In App.js I have below code -**

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Login from './Components/Login';
import { store } from "./GlobalStorage/store";
import   {GlobalProvider,GlobalConsumer} from "./GlobalStore";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <GlobalProvider value={store}> 
     <Login></Login>
     </GlobalProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Though I have exported GlobalProvider from GlobalStore.js , Application is throwing below error -**

```
Failed to compile.

./src/App.js
Attempted import error: 'GlobalProvider' is not exported from './GlobalStore'.
```

Comment: i think `default` is not required in globalstore `export default {GlobalProvider,GlobalConsumer}`

Comment: While `import { }` looks like destructuring, it's not the same as object destructuring. The syntax is related to named exports. You've mixed up [default exports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Syntax) with named exports. If you export something with just `export` (not `export default`), you can import it by name with `import { } from ...`. However, if you use `export default`, you just give the import a name (e.g. `import Store from './GlobalStore'`) and destructure it later (`const { GlobalProvider } = Store`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are exporting an object with properties `GlobalProvider` and `GlobalConsumer` as the `default` export from `GlobalStore.js`. Remove the `default` keyword and it will work as expected with regular named exports.

```js
export { GlobalProvider, GlobalConsumer };
```